# VBA go to next row after copyng from iteration

Tags: vba, sorting

I want to loop through one sheet and if a certain word is found, it should copy it to the other sheet. Now my problem is that after it copies once, it doesn't go to the next row for the next match. It just keeps copying the same match in 30 rows.

```
For Each hs In c.Range(c.Range("F1"), c.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    If InStr(hs, "+8i94") Or InStr(hs, "some") Then
        hs.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=ac.Range("A90", "A120")
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if my understanding of your problem is correct, this should do it

```
r=89    
For Each hs In c.Range(c.Range("F1"), c.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
If InStr(hs, "+8i94") Or InStr(hs, "some") Then
    r=r+1
    hs.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=ac.range("A" & r)
End If
Next
```